# Unable to access jar file for jmeter

Tags: jmeter

When I run a watch file of JMeter then in CMD error shows me that error level 1. I tried many ways but unable to access it. Please show me best way so I can run Jmeter very easily.

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: Could you please post more details about the error? perhaps a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for getting this error is downloading **Source** distribution instead of **Binary**, you need to re-download the "Binary" one:

[image]

Also make sure you properly installed [JDK or JRE](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html) and `java` executable is in your operating system [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) (so when you execute `java -version` you see your Java installation details)

More information: [How to Get Started With JMeter: Installation & Test Plans](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-get-started-jmeter-installation-test-plans)